# Set default active executable in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I want to set the default active executable to iPad simulator every time I open the project. How can we set the default active executable to iPad? Also when I create a new project iOS>Application, right pane "Product" shows iPhone. Are there any options to change it to iPad, as I will be working on iPad apps only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that in the .plist file of your app.

Comment: I don't see any such setting. Info.plist seems like a strange place for an Xcode setting. Which key in Info.plist are you referring to?

Comment: If your using xcode 4 or above, click on your project name at the top left where it shows all your .h and .m files. then go to Build Settings, then Target Device Family.